# The use of "a", "the" and "zero article" before the brands of cars

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article, zero-article

Let's say I prefer the cars made by a certain company. Which article do I use in the following context?

> I prefer **a** Volvo.
>
> I prefer **the** Volvo.
>
> I prefer Volvo.

Comment: I would say "I prefer a Volvo" or "...Volvos".

Comment: @KateBunting I don't think we can always say "a Volvo". *"I prefer a Volvo [SUV] over a Mercedes [SUV]*", sure. But not *"I prefer a Volvo over a Mercedes"*. We would say *"I prefer Volvo over Mercedes"*, *"I prefer Mac to Windows"*, or *"I prefer Pizza Hut over Dominos"*. Would you agree?

Comment: I commented that that was what I would say, not that it was the only correct version. (I would never say _prefer over_, either.)

Comment: @KateBunting I think you misunderstood me. I didn't say your comment was wrong. I was trying to see if you agreed with my view on this - when it comes to just brands, we don't use "a" in this case. But with a particular product under the brand, we do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English has only two articles, **the** and **a** (or **an**). In general, when you describe something specific, you use an article. Otherwise, you don't. Often, the use or absence of an article influences how a reader or listener interprets the meaning of a sentence.

Even though it's short, your example is complex. You might use Volvo to refer to a **brand** or you might use Volvo to refer to a specific kind of car. There are cases where all four sentences are valid, depending on the context.

In the first example below, you don't use an article because you're selecting one answer from a list of choices:

> Q: Which brand do you prefer? Volvo or Mercedes?
>
> A: I prefer Volvo.

This example could be similar to the one above, or it could be that you're referring to cars in general, so you don't use an article:

> Q: Which cars to you like better? Volvos or Mercedes?
>
> A: I prefer Volvos.

In these examples, you use an article because you're referring to a specific vehicle:

> Q: Which car do you like better? The Volvo or the Mercedes?
>
> A: I prefer the Volvo.

> Q: You can rent either a Volvo or a Mercedes. Which do you want?
>
> A: I prefer a Volvo.